# Cisco AnyConnect Command Line parse profile or command line arguments

Tags: shell, command-line, vpn, cisco

I am trying to automate a vpn connection using cisco anyconnect client. Is there a way to do this in a shell script using either an XML based Cisco Anyconnect profile or just passing credentials and server IP over the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working on one of my vpn connections.

```
cat > start_vpn.sh
#!/bin/bash
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s << EOF
connect https://your.cisco.vpn.hostname/vpn_name
here_goes_your_username
here_goes_your_passwordy
EOF
^D
# chmod +x start_vpn.sh
```

credit goes to this page:
http://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2014/05/23/automating-cisco-anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

AnyConnect comes with CLI solution.
You can find more details here.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin30/ac15userguidelines.html

If you are concerned about storing your credentials in plain text, of if you use OTP solution to authenticate, I would suggest you enable certificate based authentication.

This can be done by your network administrator and more information for that is here: https://supportforums.cisco.com/blog/152941/anyconnect-certificate-based-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I had sucess using openconnect

```
sudo openconnect --script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script ADDRESS \
   --authgroup=GROUP --user=USER
```